# Creating site in Azure using free subscription - The service is unavailable

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I am new to azure and i am exploring it now, as first step i created a free azure account and in that i created a Resource group and an App service to that resource group.

[image]

When i try to access the Url https://azurehome.azurewebsites.net/ its giving an error 'The service is unavailable.'

any help on this ?

Comment: An "App Service" is just a slot - you still have to deploy something into it.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-http-502-http-503

Comment: Have you deploy any code to the web app?

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-ae/help/4464854/scenario-5-my-website-is-throwing-http-error-503-the-service-is-unavai

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this document to troubleshoot:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-http-502-http-503

By the way, this problem may be caused by the region you choose, trying to change the region may be effective. I'm using Central US and it works fine.

If it still doesn't resolve, please provide more information.

If you need support, you can click this link:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/options/